# If you throw an object at a steel plate and the object explodes would you say that the steel plate transferred energy to the object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If you throw an object at a steel plate and the object explodes would you say that the steel plate transferred energy to the object?

EDIT: By explode I mean burst apart like a watermelon hitting a wall. I'm NOT talking about explosives.

And if you would say that then does that mean the steel plate is basically an infinite source of energy? This is one of the things I don't understand about Newtonian Physics. I guess this pertains to Newton's Third Law of Motion, for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

The moving object has kinetic energy and it transfers that to the steel plate when it hits it, but then the steel plate exerts an equal and opposite force back on the moving object and that's why it explodes.

But how do we describe this event? Do we say that the moving object transferred energy and did work on the steel plate and then the steel plate transferred energy back to the moving object and did work on it?

Answer (score 3):

> If you throw an object at a steel plate and the object explodes would you say that the steel plate transferred energy to the object?

No. In this case no energy was transferred to the watermelon by the plate. Work (transfer of energy) is force times distance. The force is large but the distance is 0. So the work is 0.

> Do we say that the moving object transferred energy and did work on the steel plate and then the steel plate transferred energy back to the moving object and did work on it?

No, the distance is 0 so no energy is transferred (work) either way. The watermelon starts with kinetic energy, that is changed into elastic potential energy, and then back to kinetic energy, all while remaining in the watermelon and not being transferred to the plate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127337/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-if-you-throw-an-object-at-a-steel-plate-and-the-obj).